# Arjun and Subhadra's marriage

Tags: krishna, arjuna, subhadra

Subhadra was the sister of Krishna, 
and Arjun was the cousin brother of Krishna, As far as I know, Kunti was Krishna's Bua (father's sister).

So if they were blood relatives, How could Arjun and Subhadra marry?

Comment: non-sagotra cousin marriage is allowed. e.g. a boy can marry his father's sister's daughter, or his mother's brother's daughter, because they belong to different gotra (that of the girl's father). you should not marry father's brother's daughter (which Islam allows).

Comment: @ram can u pls add an answer if u hv any reference..Krishna's son, grandson and Arjuna married their maternal uncle's daughter..I think such marriage now happens only in some part of India..

Comment: @YDS - that's right, non-paternal cousin marriage is allowed in Dravida Desh (below Vindhya mountains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daughter suitable for marriage.

> Manusmriti 3:5. **A woman who is not of the six generations** of the mother and of the father's gotra, is recommended to twice-born men for wedlock and conjugal union.

Kunti was biological daughter of Surasena but she was adopted by Kumtibhoja, the paternal cousin of Surasena.

> Vaisampayana continued, 'There was amongst the Yadavas a chief named Sura. He was the father of Vasudeva. And he had a daughter called Pritha, who was unrivalled for beauty on earth. And, O thou of Bharata's race, Sura, always truthful in speech, gave from friendship this his firstborn daughter unto his childless cousin and friend, the illustrious Kuntibhoja--the son of his paternal aunt--pursuant to a former promise.
>
> [Adi Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01112.htm)

So, Kunti was not full sister of Vasudeva. The generation gap is is very much between the Subhadra and Kunti so their marriage is justified.

Comment: We hv another instances.."Pradyumna married Rukmī’s daughter, and from her womb Aniruddha was born. Aniruddha then married Rukmī’s granddaughter and begot Vajra"...so I think there should be some other reasons..I heard in some part of India people still marry mother's brother's daughter..

Comment: And when it talks about generation gap, blood relations..I think we should consider biological rater than adopted..

Comment: @YDS Arjuna nwas biological son of Indra still he is considered as a kuru. In the same manner Kunti was now the daughter of Kunti Bhoj.

Comment: @YDS I am talking about  Subhadra here. This question is not about Pradyumna and Anirudha.

Comment: @SanatanDarshan, even if she was a sister, non-sagotra cousin marriage is allowed. e.g. a boy can marry his father's sister's daughter, or his mother's brother's daughter. you should not marry father's brother's daughter.