# Can I marry my paternal uncle's wife's cousin's daughter according to Hindu religion? Also how normal/extreme is it in north India?

Tags: practice, marriage, customs

Will us be blood related, as she is from my uncle's wife's side and I am from my uncle's side?

Comment: what is her gotra ? if same gotra, cannot marry. otherwise, it's allowed. still better to be not closely blood related, but as long as gotra is different, it is not prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

[This particular answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/40427/15734) can help you.

> Manusmriti 3:5. A woman who is not of the six generations of the mother and of the father's gotra is recommended to twice-born men for wedlock and conjugal union.

If it was the cousin-brother, As your uncle already married in that family, that means your Gotra is different from her gotra, It should not be a problem.

If it was a cousin-sister, better to check the gotra again, should not be an issue in that case either.

I hope you understand this difference. Anyways, better to consult some pundit for this.